# How to handle requests to clearly but wrong defined resource?

Tags: url, seo, http-status-code-404, search-engine, http-status-code-301

Given I use an CMS which makes an article available unter the following URL: `http://example.com/article/1-my-first-and-famous-article/`

Internally I can identify the requested article unequivocally by its id (1).

How should I handle requests to a wrong (typing error, manipulation, ..) URL? For example someone requests     `http://example.com/article/1-my-firsz-and-famous-article/` or `http://example.com/article/1-this-article-is-stupid-idiot/` - should I respond with http status code **301** and redirect to the right URL or with **404** and show a not found page (maybe with redirection after a few seconds). Which is the preferable way in terms of **search engine optimization**?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO. It should be moved to [webmasters.se].

Answer (score 0):

Wrong URLs will be 404 error and any existing page moved to new location will be 301 redirect